# Entity Framework Insert object with related object

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am a newbie with Entity Framework and I need to insert an object `Comment` that has a related FK object `User` into the database.

```
    public Class Comment
    {
        public int CommentID { get; set; }
        public string CommentContent { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CommentCreationTime { get; set; }
    }

public class User
{      

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }

    public string UserImageUrl{get; set;}
    public DateTime UserCreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

  public void AddComment()
  {
        User user = new User() { UserID = 1 };            
        Comment comment = new Comment() { CommentContent = "This is a comment", CommentCreationTime = DateTime.Now, User = user };

        var ctx = new WallContext();
        comments = new CommentsRepository(ctx);

        comments.AddComment(comment);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
   }
```

Ideally, with T-SQL, if I know the PRIMARY KEY of my `User` object, I could just insert my `Comment` object and specify the PK of my 'User' in the insert statement.

I have tried to do the same with Entity Framework and it doesn't seem to work. It would be overkill to have to first fetch the `User` object from the database just to insert a new 'Comment'.

Please, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to attach the user object to the context so that the context knows its an existing entity

```
  public void AddComment()
  {
       var ctx = new WallContext();

        User user = new User() { UserID = 1 };  

        ctx.Users.Attach(user);

        Comment comment = new Comment() { CommentContent = "This is a comment", CommentCreationTime = DateTime.Now, User = user };

        comments = new CommentsRepository(ctx);

        comments.AddComment(comment);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
   }
```

Comment: doesn't attaching the user to the context result in a db call? Is there any way to insert a object with related entities in one round trip